# How can I take out the element from a String?

Tags: java

For example, if I have a string "Hello how are you". After I use the `split()` to separate all the elements, I want to put "Hello" to a variable, also same as the remainings, which method should I use to do it as it is not an ArrayList so I can't use the index.
Lots of thanks.

Comment: Using `String.split()` will already put each word into an array variable.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean by "also same as the remainings"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can I put 2 items in the same string, like putting "how" and "are" together in the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same like this :-

```
String input = "Hello how are you";
String[] splittedString = input.split(" ");
System.out.println(splittedString[0]);
```

Comment: Can I put 2 items in the same string, like putting "how" and "are" together in a new variable?

Comment: You could do that. String howare = splittedString[0] + splittedString[1]

Comment: @akshayrajkore thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I put 2 items in the same string, like putting "how" and "are" together in a new variable?

You can use [`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) (where the second argument is a `limit`). Something like

```
String str = "Hello how are you";
String[] parts = str.split("\\s+", 2);
System.out.printf("First Word: %s%n", parts[0]);
System.out.printf("Rest of the Words: %s%n", parts[1]);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
First Word: Hello
Rest of the Words: how are you
```